# How to initialize tabs-swipeable-wrap manually

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7, swiper.js

I'm using swiper with framwork7 to have swipeable tabs, it comes with this class tabs-swipeable-wrap which allows get it.

However, I need to create dynamic slides so what I have tried so far is append and appendSlide.
The best result I have is swipeable slides however I can't go more than the 2nd slide as it jumps back to the first one.

I have tried calling 
update();
also tried with and without tabs-swipeable-wrap class

All works except for the swiping.

Is there a way to call tabs-swipeable-wrap manually maybe!?

Comment: UPDATE:
I have created a JSFiddle to replicate one of my attempts to implement this;
http://jsfiddle.net/wztgb8e5/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution, simple:

`var mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper`

So get the inilized swiper and use update(); after appending instead of reinilizing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/wztgb8e5/6/

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with script. You have tabbar with id linked to tab1,tab2,tab3 where as you are appending swiper slider with id tab0,tab1,tab2. this will repeat for each click. so there is match for tabbar href and tabs ids. if you rectify it. then it will work fine. I have made some update to the fiddle check that too.

Comment: Thanks. I did take care of that in my code but its not in the jsdiffle :)